# Align two strings perfectly (python)

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to align the spaces and characters of two strings perfectly?

I have two functions, resulting in two strings.

One just adds a " " between a list of digits:

```
digits = 34567
new_digits = 3 4 5 6 7
```

The second function takes the string and prints out the index of the string, such that:

```
digits = 34567
index_of_digits = 1 2 3 4 5
```

Now the issue that I am having is when the length of the string is greater than 10, the alignment is off:

[image: This is what I am getting]

I am supposed to get something like this:

[image: What I am supposed to get]

Please advice.

Comment: I have managed to complete the assignment, which was to make a memory game - in which the player has to match the pars of number / digits. The only thing left for me to do is figure out how to align the index number with the digit itself.

Comment: Show your current formatting code.  How are the numbers stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your digits are in a list, you can use `format` to space them uniformly:

```
L = [3,4,2,5,6,3,6,2,5,1,4,1]
print(''.join([format(n,'3') for n in range(1,len(L)+1)]))
print(''.join([format(n,'3') for n in L]))
```

Or with f-string formatting (Python 3.6+):

```
L = [3,4,2,5,6,3,6,2,5,1,4,1]
print(''.join([f'{n+1:3}' for n in range(len(L))]))
print(''.join([f'{n:3}' for n in L]))
```

Output:

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
  3  4  2  5  6  3  6  2  5  1  4  1
```

Ref: [join](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [format](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#format), [range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#range), [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed my problem